# IE Error, Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

```
 function charCount(){
  $.doTimeout('poll', 150, function(){
      messageVal = $('#messageLabel textarea').val();

      messageLength = messageVal.length; //IE BREAKS HERE

      $('#messageLength').html(messageLength + '/140')
      if(messageLength > 140){
          $('#messageLength').not('.inv').addClass('inv')
      }else{
          $('#messageLength.inv').removeClass('inv')
      }
      return false;
  })

}
$('#messageLabel textarea').change(charCount).keyup(charCount);
```

Gives the following error in Internet Explorer 7.0 (and maybe other versions too).

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

Any ideas  on what is causing this error?

Comment: "Nope, not the solution. Thanks" - Try commenting out stuff until the error doesn't appear, and that will isolate the statement that invokes this.

Comment: @meder You're absolutely right. I already edited the question though. Problem is at line 5 (.length).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you don't use the `var` keyword, IE browser search for `messageLength` in the global context and it finds it... you have element with that ID.

Trying to assign number to HTML element fails.

To solve this, just declare `messageLength` as local variable:

```
var messageLength = messageVal.length; //IE WON'T BREAK HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try yo replace :

```
messageVal = $('#messageLabel textarea').val();
```

with

```
messageVal = $('#messageLabel textarea').text();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nope, not the solution. Thanks.

Comment: try to do a typeof(messageVal)

Comment: strange it must work you sure the error comes from messageVal.length ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the .change() is having some problem in IE.Please remove it and see if it is working.

Also try using .html() instead of .val().

Comment: Nope, not the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

look here [simple test](http://jsfiddle.net/AEMLoviji/M9rKx/). textarea does not support value property. you can get it via text property

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error, however, it was because I added the JQuery library to the master page and there was a duplicate library declaration elsewhere the same page.